# DBSCAN with a larger neighbourhood

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am using `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN` on my dataset. However, it tends to classify some of my data points as noise, even though they are not. However, if I increase `eps` even more, it will start merging unrelated clusters. I figured that my best attempt would be if I kept the clustering phase the same, but increased the allowed range for the "neighbour finding" phase. Is there such a possibility? My only other approach would be to build a kd-tree of all non-noise points, and for each noise point to look for the closest non-noise point and evaluate if they belong together. However, of course it would be better if this was working in a built-in way.

Comment: DBSCAN assumes that all clusters have a uniform variance. There are extensions of DBSCAN such as HDBSCAN or OPTICS that understand that the spread around cluster centroids can vary. `scikit-learn` has OPTICS built-in; [HDBSCAN](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_hdbscan_works.html) is available via pip.